# removing a Button from a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

Is it possible to remove a `Button` from a `LinearLayout` that the free space can be used by other objects?

I only know this which makes the Button invisible.

```
.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Kind Regards,

k.j.

Comment: try `.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: why the unaccept now?

Comment: I am so sorry about that. All answers are correct but I'm new and I don't know which answer I should set as accepted. I tried so accept all but I doesn't work. :-( As I said I am really sorry about that. :-(  I selected the answer from "Stack Overflow User" because it seems that he was the fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to just change invisible to `gone` like below code:

```
yourbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

if you are using gone it's hide button with remove occupy space in layout!

after you need show button using `visible` it's automatically re-occupy spaces for a button in layout like below sample code:

```
yourbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

if you are `invisible` it's hides only button and it's does not remove occupy space button in layout like below code:

```
yourbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
   .setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

`public static final int GONE`

Added in API level 1

**This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility**.

Constant Value: 8 (0x00000008)

`public static final int INVISIBLE`

Added in API level 1

**This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.**

Answer (score 1):

you can change the visibility of the button to GONE ,using

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

using View.INVISIBLE will make the view still take space, so it's probably not what you want.

another alternative is to really remove it , by using:

```
linearLayout.removeView(textView);
```